# Generating new a column in dataframe given value falls within a certain range of another column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[random.randrange(0, 9, 1) for i in range(10000000)],
                   'B':[random.randrange(0, 9, 1) for i in range(10000000)]})
```

That may look like this:

```
    A   B
0   8   3
1   3   0
2   8   4
3   6   5
4   8   2
...
```

I'd like to generate a new column called Eq. This column confirms if A and B row values fall within a certain range. If so, the number 1 is appended, if not 0 is appended.

If the range is 2 the result should look like this:

```
    A   B   Eq
0   8   3    0
1   3   0    0
2   8   4    0
3   6   5    1
4   8   2    0
...
```

```
Essentially:
8 does NOT fall in range of (3-2,3+2)
3 does NOT fall in range of (0-2,0+2)
6 DOES fall in range of (5-2,5+2)
```

In my first attempt, I wrote a simple function to apply to each row of the df.

```
def CountingMatches(row, range_limit):
    if row['A'] in range (-range_limit + row['B'], range_limit+row['B']):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

```
df['Eq'] = df.apply(CountingMatches, axis=1, range_limit=3)
```

This worked but took an incredibly long time, so kinda useless.

I then used my function with swifter https://towardsdatascience.com/speed-up-your-pandas-processing-with-swifter-6aa314600a13

```
df['Eq'] = df.swifter.apply(CountingMatches, axis=1, range_limit=3)
```

This also took a really long time.

I then checked how long it would take to check if the columns matched, no range.

```
df['Eq'] = (df['A'].astype(int) == df['B'].astype(int)).astype(int)
```

This was incredibly fast ~ 1s.

Given this hopeful result, I tried to incorporate the ranges.

```
range_limit=2
df['Eq'] = (df['A'].astype(int) in range(df['B'].astype(int)-range_limit,df['B'].astype(int) + range_limit)).astype(int)
```

But I get the following error, rightfully so:

```
'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

How can I efficiently complete this task on this dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html). It should be fast.

```
df['Eq'] = df['A'].between(df['B'].sub(2), df['B'].add(2)).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 2):

This shouldn't take much longer than maybe 2x the time it took when you checked if the columns matched (as int):

```py
range_limit = 2

lower_limits = df['B'] - range_limit
upper_limits = df['B'] + range_limit
df['Eq'] = ((lower_limits < df['A']) & (df['A'] < upper_limits)).astype(int)

# df['Eq'] = (((df['B'] - 2) < df['A']) & (df['A'] < (df['B'] + 2))).astype(int)
```

[It took about 0.1s on colab.]